# visual c++ 2008 release problem

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I've made a simple C++ program in VC++ 2008 Pro and it runs fine in the pc I used to develop it but when I run it in a pc without VC++ installed, it just gives me a

"This application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect"

error. I fixed this before by statically linking my project but now when I try to do /MT or /MTD , I get a slew of link errors and it just won't go...

I've also tried installing the vs 2008 redist package too, still doesn't work.

Comment: If you look in the Windows event log of the system with the failure, you will get a clearer idea of the assemblies that are required.

Answer (score 1):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877418/including-ms-c-runtime-in-vs2005-generated-msi/).

Essentially the C/C++ runtimes are now deployed as side-by-side win32 assemblies. The embedded manifest in the compiled EXE will determine what dlls it binds to from the C:\Windows\WinSxS folder.

One question: is this a release or debug build? I would try a release build to make sure it's not a debug runtime issue (which I believe won't be present on a PC that doesn't have visual studio on it).